# Firebase Authenticatoin - onAuthStateChanged called multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Whenever I render the home page or account page my session is sometimes lost. I have a function called `isSignedIn()` that checks if the uid exists. Sometimes, when I refresh the homepage, it returns false. When I hit my account endpoint it returns false too even though it's true on the previous page. Any ideas on why this is happening?

How my app works:
When a user logs in I take the uid from client side and hit an auth endpoint.

```
function createServerSession(user) {

    // Get secret token from Firebase for current session

  firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)
    .then(function(idToken) {

   // Get session on my Node server for server user identification
  if (idToken) {

    fetch('/firebaseauth?idtoken=' + encodeURIComponent(idToken) + '&username=' + encodeURIComponent(user.email.split('@')[0]), {
      credentials:'include'
    }).then(function(data){
      if (window.location.pathname === '/' && document.getElementById('login').innerHTML.trim() === 'Join') {
        redirect('/');
      }
      if (window.location.href.includes('login')) {
        redirect('/');
      }
    })
  }

})
}
```

Then it hits my node.js code to store the session:

```
app.get('/firebaseauth', function (req, res) {
if (! req.session.idToken) {
firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(req.query.idtoken).then(function(decodedToken)            {
  req.session.username = req.query.username
  req.session.idToken = decodedToken.uid;
  req.session.save(function(){
    res.json(true)
  })
})
```

This approach works fine most of the time, but some instances it will send multiple requests. The highest amount being 7400 at one point. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure how you are using this, but I recommend you call firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken() without forcing refresh. You could have some loop in your code. Calling getToken with true will force a refresh of the id token. This will also trigger onAuthStateChanged. You may be calling your routine again from there which is causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Since posting this issue, I've switched hosts from GAE to Heroku and that fixed it. I know the functionality with node.js is in beta so maybe that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting this issue, I've switched hosts from GAE to Heroku and that fixed it. I know the functionality with node.js is in beta so maybe that was it